# Compare innertext and switch with another innertext

Tags: c#, xml

Guys I am completely stumped on this one.

Basically my setup is this:
I am reading a text file that has some data in it, from which I've successfully extracted only the needed information.

```
string[] nameAnimals = new string[lines.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
nameAnimals[i] = lines[i].Substring(0, 14).TrimEnd(trimArray);
}
textBox1.Text = nameAnimals.ToString();

//textBox1 text is MonkeyElephantTigerZebra
```

I am calling my function like so

```
readingXML(nameAnimals);
```

And this is how it's declared

```
public void readingXML(string[] checkAnimals)
```

Then I am reading two different XML files which have the same layout, and only differ in one InnerText. (XML # 2 doesn't contain as much `data` as XML # 1)

```
<Root><!-- This is first XML -->
    <data>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        <NAME>Monkey</NAME>
        <PRICE>1240</Price>
    </data>
<data>
        <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        <NAME>Tiger</NAME>
        <PRICE>2500</Price>
    </data>
<data>
        <NUMBER>3</NUMBER>
        <NAME>Elephant</NAME>
        <PRICE>4810</Price>
    </data>
<data>
        <NUMBER>4</NUMBER>
        <NAME>Zebra</NAME>
        <PRICE>5600</Price>
    </data>
</Root>



<Root><!-- This is second XML -->
        <data>
            <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
            <NAME>Gorilla</NAME>
            <PRICE>1240</Price>
        </data>
    <data>
            <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
            <NAME>Bengal</NAME>
            <PRICE>2500</Price>
        </data>
    </Root>
<!-- The NAME.InnerText will always be related
between these two XML's only via NUMBER.InnerText -->
```

Now, I want to compare my string (I am guessing somehow with `string.Contains`) from that text file to the `NAME.InnerText` from XML # 1, get it's `NUMBER.InnerText`, search for the `NUMBER.InnerText` in XML # 2, get `NAME.InnerText` from XML # 2 and then show it in textBox1.
If for instance, the `NUMBER.InnerText` from XML # 1 isn't found in XML # 2, just get `PRICE.InnerText` from XML # 1. So that at the end I get string GorillaElephantBengalZebra

And my data in textBox1, ideally, after getting the PRICE.InnerText would be something like this, formatting doesn't matter at this point.

```
Gorilla - price 1240
Elephant - price 4810
Bengal - price 2500
Zebra - price 5600
```

I am way in over my head, or maybe I am over thinking this one.

Also, does it seem kind of a messy way so far to do what's needed ?

I've been googling for days but I am no closer to finding a solution.

Cheers

Comment: have you tried linq to xml?

Answer (score 0):

You want no repeated elements then, It looks like you could use a dictionary, and just combine elements.
Use as key the NUMBER and the entire object as value, so you will have not repeated elements.
 So you could create a class like this:

```
     class myXMLAnimals {
        public myXMLAnimals(string  id)
        { NUMBER = id; }
        public string NUMBER;
        public string NAME;
        public string price;
    }
```

then create a XML paraser and interate  by the elements like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dataXML1 = "<Root><!-- This is first XML -->    <data><NUMBER>1</NUMBER><NAME>Monkey</NAME><PRICE>1240</PRICE>    </data><data><NUMBER>2</NUMBER><NAME>Tiger</NAME><PRICE>2500</PRICE>    </data><data><NUMBER>3</NUMBER><NAME>Elephant</NAME><PRICE>4810</PRICE>    </data><data><NUMBER>4</NUMBER><NAME>Zebra</NAME><PRICE>5600</PRICE>    </data></Root>";

        string dataXML2 = "<Root><!-- This is second XML --><data>    <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>    <NAME>Gorilla</NAME>    <PRICE>1240</PRICE>  </data>  <data>    <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>    <NAME>Bengal</NAME>    <PRICE>2500</PRICE></data>    </Root>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(dataXML1);
        XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(dataXML2);

        Dictionary<string, myXMLAnimals> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, myXMLAnimals>();

        List<XDocument> myXMLDocumentsToCompare = new List<XDocument>();
        myXMLDocumentsToCompare.Add(doc);
        myXMLDocumentsToCompare.Add(doc2);
        //You can add more documents if you need to!

        foreach (XDocument documento in myXMLDocumentsToCompare)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("New Document!");

            string lastKey = "";
            //I assume that you only have 3 elements per object, number, name and price, you have to addapt it as you need.
            foreach (XElement element in documento.Descendants().Where(p => p.HasElements == false))
            {
                string keyName = element.Name.LocalName;


                Console.WriteLine("> lastKey = " + lastKey);

                if (keyName.Equals("NUMBER"))
                {
                    lastKey = element.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine("New element!:" + lastKey);
                    if (!dataDictionary.ContainsKey(lastKey))
                    {
                        dataDictionary.Add(lastKey, new myXMLAnimals(element.Value));
                    }

                }
                else if (keyName.Equals("NAME")) // remove this if if you dontwant to replace the NAME
                {
                    dataDictionary[lastKey].NAME = element.Value;
                }
                else if (keyName.Equals("PRICE")) // remove this if if you dontwant to replace the price
                {
                    dataDictionary[lastKey].price = element.Value;
                }



                Console.WriteLine(keyName + " = " + element.Value);
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("THIS IS THE RESULT:");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, myXMLAnimals> pair in dataDictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value.NAME+", Price:" + pair.Value.price);
        }

       Console.Beep();
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
```

Just want to let you know that the XML that you have there has some errors, the "PRICE" tag close with "price" and you should fix it to make it work :)

So the result is like:

[image]

Please let me know what you think!

Comment: Okay guys, sorry it took me a while to get back at you. The thing is I can't use linq because it's dotnet 2.0. Nevertheless all these are doing is just comparing two XML's ... I need some IF statement that checks my input string MonkeyElephantTigerZebra ... string.Contains or something (first part of my code, how I am reading lines with my "for" cycle). Thanks anyway, you've given me an idea as to where my thoughts should be going. I'll try to solve my problem in the next few days, if no final solution is given.

Answer (score 0):

LinqToXml I think it's the way to go

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\animals.xml");
var el = xdoc.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
var datas =
    from data in el.Elements()
    select new { Number = data.Element("NUMBER").Value, Name = data.Element("NAME").Value, Price = data.Element("PRICE").Value} ;

//data it's going to be an IEnumerable<anonymous> that have the properties Number, Name, Price
```

Do the same with the other Xml File and then you are working with objects and I think it's going to be simpler..

*EDIT*

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\animals.xml");
var el = xdoc.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
var datas =
    from data in el.Elements()
    select new { Number = data.Element("NUMBER").Value, Name = data.Element("NAME").Value, Price = data.Element("PRICE").Value} ;

var xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\animals2.xml");
var el2 = xdoc2.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
var datas2 =
    from data in el2.Elements()
    select new { Number = data.Element("NUMBER").Value, Name = data.Element("NAME").Value, Price = data.Element("PRICE").Value };

var result = datas.Select(x =>
{
    var d2 = datas2.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Number == x.Number);
    if ( d2 != null)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} - price {1}", d2.Name, d2.Price);
    }
    return string.Format("{0} - price {1}", x.Name, x.Price);
});

//and result has IEnumerable<string> with the output

Gorilla - 1240
Bengal - 2500 
Elephant - 4810 
Zebra - 5600
```